# LINQ Source Code Available

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-2.0

I'm using a .Net 2 project and am missing LINQ.

I cannot use 3rd party tools or try using the System.Core hack to get it to work so I was thinking that if the LINQ source code is available I could just copy the extension methods and create a class in my project.

I mainly need it for Array, List type querying etc

Thanks

Comment: I would not do it :) ! is like to say, you find the whole source code of .NET Framework 4.0 and try to build/compile it against .NET 3 ?!

Comment: I thought they were just extension methods so should compile ok.

Comment: Extension methods aren't in C# 2.0

Comment: if you need Linq then just upgrade to .NET 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft implementation of LINQ source is not available for you to use. LINQ will not work with .NET 2.0. You will need at least .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [mono's LINQ source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/c1b43669320f96e4a2a482d993b7b36bb5e59496/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Linq/Enumerable.cs). It is highly compatible with .NET's LINQ.

**Update:** Even better, [original .NET source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq) now is available.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try [LINQBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is not merely classes, it is upgraded compiler as well to understand Anonymous classes, methods, lambda expressions etc. You can use LINQ in 2.0 as well. Create seperate project, set framework 3.5. And it will work in 2.0 projects. Only thing u will miss is intellisense in VS 2005.

Comment: I Disagree, he will need to have .NET Framework 3.5 installed on the target machine so this solution is not relying only on .NET 2.0

Comment: @davide, definately 3.5 will be required to be on system. But you can use it within 2.0 projects.

Answer (score 0):

Old Question, but interesting.

Source code of linq (part of .Net framework) is now available
[Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=linq)

Also, in github
[github-Microsoft NET Reference Source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/tree/master/System.Data.Linq)